# Как узнать все вхождения символа в строке в Java?

Tags: java, строки, indexof

Например, имеем строку "кровоточивость", и нужно узнать индекс каждой буквы "о",как это сделать,не переводя строку в массив?

Comment: А самому подумать никак?

Comment: @Санаев , я сделал это с помощью перевода строки в массив символов и его перебора,и мне стало интересно,можно ли это сделать как то по проще не меняя строку,в документации про String ничего подходящего не нашёл,там методы выводят или первое вхождение символа или последнее или с заданной позиции,поэтому и задал вопрос тут

Comment: Вопрос должен звучать полностью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void indexsCharO(String str){
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        Character value = new Character(str.charAt(i));

        if(value.equals(new Character('о')))
            System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
}
```

Можно сделать также чтоб результат записывался в файл,вносился в вектор и другую коллекцию, массив и что душа пожелает. 
Версия по короче:

```
static void indexsCharO(String str){
    for(int i=0; i< str.length(); i++){
        if(str.charAt(i) == 'о') System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: @АлександрКудрявцев ,спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void getCharPlaces(String word, char inspectChar, int currentIndex ) {
    if(currentIndex < word.length()) {
        int up = word.indexOf(inspectChar, currentIndex) + 1;
        System.out.println("current position = " + (up - 1));
        if(up - 1 == word.lastIndexOf(inspectChar)) return;
        getCharPlaces(word, inspectChar, up);
    }
}
```

Ну и пример старта

```
getCharPlaces("кровоточивость", 'о', 0);
```